# Free memory of cv::Mat loaded using FileStorage API

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I'm working on a system that continuously loads and releases OpenCV Matrices using OpenCV FileStorage API. These matrices hold images feature descriptors. In concrete the piece of code that does the job is this one:

```
descriptors.create(rows, cols, type);

...

for (cv::FileNodeIterator it = keypointsSequence.begin(); it != keypointsSequence.end(); it++, idx++) {

    ...

    cv::Mat featureVector;
    (*it)["descriptor"] >> featureVector;

    featureVector.copyTo(descriptors.row(idx));
    featureVector.release();
}
```

As I understand from [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/) a `cv::Mat` is released only when it was created using `Mat::create`. Though I'm using the create method, its content is being copied from the loaded matrix.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is `featureVector` being correctly released and hence its memory deallocated? Or do I have to delete it manually?
2. How correct is it defining `featureVector` inside the loop? And how does it impact the overall performance (specially in memory)?

I would strongly appreciate any insight about this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Post you mention show how Mat 'can' be released manually, but it doesn't mean that you 'need' to release it yourself. Mat is a smart pointer that deals with all kinds of deallocation by itself. Personally I never had a need to use release function myself (and I am using OpenCV for years).
2. It reallocates its memory only if its size is changed. And that is not the case. So defining it outside of the loop will prevent a lot of unneeded allocation and deallocations.

Besides, why are you using temporary Mat (featureVector) instead of writing directly to descriptors.row(idx)?

Edit (response to comment 3):

Your error looks weird. Just to be sure that the code is working fine I wrote very short test code and it worked as it should. Here it is:

```
Mat src = imread(argv[1],-1);

FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "imgs" << "[" << "{" << "img" << src.row(500) << "}" << "]";
fs.release();

FileStorage fs2("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat src2(src.size(), src.type(), Scalar(0));
FileNode imgsNode= fs2["imgs"];
for(FileNodeIterator it = imgsNode.begin(); it != imgsNode.end(); ++it )
    (*it)["img"] >> src2.row(500);
fs2.release();

imwrite("res.pgm",src2);
```

As you can see no temporary image is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I was doubtful about if OpenCV was dealing with the destruction of this matrix. That's the reason I was calling the release function at the end of the loop and keeping it in loop scope. About using featureVector as temporary variable, I did it as in the usage examples of >> operator. I never thought it was possible to use it directly onto a row since as far as I understand, copying rows between matrices requires using a temporal matrix.

Comment: There are enough cases where temporary matrix is needed, but copying is not one of them. Operations like A.row(i).copyTo(B.row(j)) is perfectly legal as long as they have same width.

Comment: Seems I hastened to accept the answer. I got home and tried your suggestions, I factored out the featureVector variable declaration as you suggested and now I'm not copying the row but instead using featureVector to point it:

featureVector = descriptors.row(idx);
(*it)["descriptor"] >> featureVector;

Anyway seems I still do need it since when I write directly to the row it gives me the following error:

error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘cv::FileNode::operator[](const char*) const(((const char*)"descriptor")) >> cv::Mat::row(int) const(idx)’

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort but I'm obtaining the same error. I'm closing this question but I've opened a new question to follow this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107813/compilation-error-while-reading-a-cvmat-from-a-cvfilenode-without-temporary

Comment: You are welcome. This is indeed weird error. Btw, I am using Windows 7 Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.4.5.